# Send email catch errors

Tags: c#, email

How can I shoot except in case of e-mail not sent?

I have a class to send emails, as follows:

```
public class Email {
 private SmtpClient SMTPCliente;
 private string From;

 public Email(string smtp, int port, bool ssl = false) {
  SMTPCliente = new SmtpClient(smtp, port);
  SMTPCliente.EnableSsl = ssl;
  SMTPCliente.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  SMTPCliente.Timeout = 5000;
 }

 public void Login(string username, string password) {
  From = username;
  SMTPCliente.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
 }

 public void Send(string message, string assunto, string destinatario, string attach = "") {
  MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
  msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
  msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
  msg.From = new MailAddress(From);
  msg.Body = message;
  msg.Subject = assunto;
  msg.To.Add(destinatario);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attach))
   msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attach));

  SMTPCliente.Send(msg);

  //msg.Dispose();
  //msg.Attachments.Dispose();
 }
```

I am using a try, catch block to try to catch the exception, however, nothing happens ... the program runs infinitely and does not fire any errors.

```
try {
 Email email = new Email("smtp.live.com", 10);
 email.Login("this@gmail.com", "password");
 email.Send("My message", "Assunto", "destino@email.com");
} catch (FormatException) {
 //invalid email pattern
 //A cadeia de caracteres especificada não está no formato necessário para um endereço de email.
} catch (ArgumentException) {
 //no attachment
 //O parâmetro 'fileName' não pode ser uma cadeia de caracteres vazia.
} catch (Exception ex) {
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

the dummy smtp data were only used for the case

Comment: Should you be getting an error?

Comment: I removed the port, and now the timeout exception was fired ...